# rename database in psql

Tags: postgresql

Could anybody help me to rename database in postgresql from the Linux shell

```
ALTER DATABASE name RENAME TO newname
```

The above statement doesn't execute

Comment: CountZero beat me to it but yes, you must make sure that nobody (including yourself) is connected to the database when renaming it.  E.g. to rename database "xyz", connect to the default database "posgtres" and issue "ALTER DATABASE xyz RENAME TO abc" from there.

Comment: Please paste here the error message you get. "Doesn't execute" is not enough.

Comment: I assume you know that you have to login to psql, and not to the same database that you are trying to rename?

Comment: Silly me.  I only have one postgres database, and you can't run the SQL workbench until you click on the database, and once you've clicked on the database, you have connected to it (chicken/egg problem).  Unlike Microsoft SQL, I don't see an obvious way to disconnect from it.  Now I remember why I never use Postgres.  Just the basics are a real pain to administer.

Answer (score 27):

This may be a stupidly obvious question.  Are you running psql as the postgres user?

e.g.

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
# alter database FOO rename to BAR;
# \q
```

Comment: I had the same issue, rewriting it in lowercase made it work!

Comment: By the way the error was this: postgres-# ALTER DATABASE oldname RENAME TO newname;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "|"
LINE 1: |l
        ^

Answer (score 22):

Which version of postgresql? From the [8.1 Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-alterdatabase.html):

> ALTER DATABASE name RENAME TO newname;
>
> Only the database owner or a superuser
>   can rename a database; non-superuser
>   owners must also have the CREATEDB
>   privilege. The current database cannot
>   be renamed. (Connect to a different
>   database if you need to do that.)

Answer (score 11):

You might need privileges to rename db. Only db owner or super user can do that, owner also needs a createdb privilege.

Also the database you're connected to cannot be renamed, you need to connect to a different one

Comment: This was the issue for me. I was connected to the database I was trying to rename.

Comment: Sorry but I can't get it. How can I run a command on the DB if I'm not connected to this DB?..

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rename a database you are connected to. Make sure you are disconnected before changing the dbname.
In PGAdmin, you can just right-click on the database itself, go to properties, and rename it from there.
As others have pointed out, you may also try the command :
ALTER DATABASE (DB NAME) RENAME TO (NEW DB NAME);

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect database (`Ctrl + F2` in DataGrip)

And then:

```
$ psql -U postgres
postgres=# ALTER DATABASE db_a RENAME TO db_b;
```

GL

Answer (score -1):

Login directly to the Postgres server and execute the following:

```
PGPASSWORD=abcd1234 psql "host=101.1.2.154 sslmode=prefer sslrootcert=./Keys/server-ca.pem sslcert=./Keys/client-cert.pem sslkey=./Keys/client-key.pem port=5432 user=postgres" --command="ALTER DATABASE source_db_name RENAME TO new_target_db_name;"
```

output is:
ALTER DATABASE

Answer (score -12):

Below given are the steps for renaming the database in postgresql.

> 1) Right click on database and choose refresh.
>   2) Right click again and choose properties option.
>   3) Under the properties tab, you can change the name with the one that you desire.